# How do I scale my spell target indicator to match the radius of OverlapSphere

Tags: unity, mathematics, geometry, scale

I have a spell system in which some spells have an Area of Effect. To get the targets I use `Physics.OverlapSphere`. I show the player an indication of the spell's radius by spawning a Unity plane primitive at the target position and scaling it to match the radius of the spell.

[image: Screenshot of the spell radius indicator]

**How would I scale my spell target indicator visual to correctly match the radius of OverlapSphere?**

I have tried setting the scale of the plane's X,Y,Z to radius * 2, but this does not seem to align with the overlap sphere radius.

```
data.indicatorInstance.transform.DOScale(data.parent.radius * 2, 0.5f);
```

And just for completeness sake, below is the OverlapSphere call.

```
Physics.OverlapSphere(targetPosition, data.parent.radius)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default Plane primitive in Unity has a width of 10 units, so its center-to-edge distance is 5 units.

So if you want the edges of your plane to kiss the edges of your OverlapSphere test, you'll want to divide your radius by `5.0f` to get the right scale factor for the plane..

However, the visible circles in your indicator are smaller than the extents of the plane itself, so you might want to use a smaller denominator to align the sphere check with these rings instead.

To find the appropriate number, place both your target indicator plane and a default Unity sphere primitive at the origin, with scale (1, 1, 1). Uniformly scale the sphere primitive until it lines up with the ring on your target indicator you want to match to the sphere check. The default sphere has a radius of 0.5, so this radius is half the scale factor you used.

eg. If I have to scale my sphere primitive to a scale of (6.2, 6.2, 6.2) to line up with the right circle on the indicator, then the radius of that circle is 0.5 * 6.2 = 3.1. So to match this to the radius of an OverlapSphere check I need to divide the check radius by `3.1f` to get my plane's scale factor.